# Django form __init__ overload making overridden form save method not work?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a django form that occurs on an object detail page. I'd like to prepopulate a hidden form field with the slug of the object detail page it occurs on. I also have an overridden save method on the same form so that I can provide some processing and save it to the proper model. However, when I introduce the overridden **init** on the form to prepopulate the field (and provide that **init** with the slug on the form call), the overridden save stops working. Why is this?

My code:

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^my_object_detail/(?P<slug>[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,80})/$', my_object_detail, name = 'my_object_detail'),
```

**views.py**

```
def my_object_detail(request, slug, template_name='my_plan_detail_page.html', **kwargs):

    my_object = get_object_or_404(MyObjects, slug=slug)
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None, slug=slug)

    if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

**forms.py**

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'my-class-1','placeholder':'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='', max_length=30, required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'my-class-1','placeholder':'Last Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'my-class-2','placeholder':'Email Address'}))
    interested_in = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, widget=forms.HiddenInput())

    def __init__(self, request=None, slug=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = request
        self.slug = slug
        super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['interested_in'].widget.attrs['value'] = slug

    def save(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data
        first_name = data['first_name']
        last_name = data['last_name']
        email = data['email']
        interested_in = data['interested_in']
        if settings.CURRENT_HOST == 'host-1':
            lead_source = "host-1"
        else:
            lead_source = 'host-2'
        new_contact = MyContact(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, email=email, interested_in=interested_in, lead_source=lead_source)
        new_contact.save()
```

Possibly pertinent - if I remove the overloaded init, and make form call in views.py look like this, the overridden save method works just fine:

```
form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
```

Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've changed the signature of the form initialization, so it's now expecting request and slug as the first two arguments, but you're actually passing the form data as the first one when you initialize it.

Change it to this:

```
def __init__(self, args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
    self.slug = kwargs.pop('slug', None)
    ...etc...
```

Comment: Awesome. It looks like I don't even need to include the "self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)" line; it still works without it. Thank you so much